# floating images in reveal.js using markdown

Tags: css, reveal.js

I am trying to get an image to float to the right in a reveal.js presentation.  I would like to include any custom css and html in the slides.md file for portability.

here's an example slide code:

```
--- 

## Title

    <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff", style="height:30vh; background-color:white; float:right;"/>

* List item 1 blah blah blah blah blah 
* List item 2
* List item 3

---
```

This works partially.  The image is shown alongside the list if the list elements fit.  However, if the page is narrow or the list elements are long, then the list ends up below the image.

Is there a way to force the text to line-wrap?
As a more general question, is there a way to wrap reveal.js text around images?